# How to permit parameters for Spree API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

How do I permit parameters for a Spree API request?

I added a new parameter, :note, in the following file:

spree_api/app/helpers/spree/api/api_helpers.rb

```
Spree::Api::ApiHelpers.module_eval do
   @@order_attributes = [
     :id, :number, :item_total, :total, :ship_total, :state, :adjustment_total,
     :user_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :completed_at, :payment_total,
     :shipment_state, :payment_state, :email, :special_instructions, :channel,
     :included_tax_total, :additional_tax_total,      :display_included_tax_total,
     :display_additional_tax_total, :tax_total, :currency, :notes
   ]
end
```

However, every time I send a :note parameter, I get the following response in my console:

```
Unpermitted parameters: id, number, item_total, total, state, adjustment_total, user_id, completed_at, payment_total, shipment_state, payment_state, created_at, updated_at, currency, additional_tax_total, channel, included_tax_total, notes
```

What's the correct way to add permitted params to a Spree API call?

I'm using the following gems:

```
spree (2.4.3.beta)
  spree_api (= 2.4.3.beta)
```

My Rails version is: Rails 4.1.8

Comment: It seems your request has some wrong parameter names. Please provide the full code of request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spree uses a variable per model for permitted parameters and for the api parameters defined in the gem itself, you can extend this in the spree config.

For `order_attributes` you would add the following line to add customer_id to the api response `config/initializers/spree.rb`:

```
Spree::Api::ApiHelpers.order_attributes << :customer_id
```

to add customer_id to the permitted_attributes you need to add to the permitted attributes variable.

```
Spree::PermittedAttributes.order_attributes << :customer_id
```

Comment: It appeared I had to use Spree::Api::ApiHelpers.order_attributes << :notes in order to extend the API permitted attributes. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 4):

For `order_attributes` you would use the following line

I believe this in your order_decorator.rb:

```
Spree::PermittedAttributes.order_attributes << :your_attribute
```

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer. I misread the question. Permitted attributes are a separate helper file.